# using custom font twice with different style Titanium

Tags: fonts, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm using custom font in titanium sdk and i'm using font `Myriad Pro` with semi-bold style and reguler style on android every thing works fine but on iphone i'm using the full name of the font not the file name so i can't use the reguler

i have tried to use `fontStyle` but with no success
any help?

Comment: Code? Where you have used the fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS applications expect the font's PostScript name as stated here in the docs:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts-section-29004935_CustomFonts-Findingafont%27sPostScriptname

The postScript name will differ for the regular and bold type